# Processing 2d array outputting garbage

Tags: arrays, processing

I'm trying to make a 10 x 10 array of 0s in Processing. When I run my code, I get `[[I@1335f392` as the output. What am I doing wrong?

```
int[][] myArray;

void setup()
{
  myArray = new int[10][10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
    {
      myArray[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  println(myArray);
}

void draw()
{

}
```

Comment: It is Processing language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the address of the array. In order to print the contents, you have to loop over your array (like you did when you were assigning values).

Comment: I wonder what happens if you put an integer array into iostream.  I don't suppose it's smart enough to do something clever.

Comment: I would not count on it.

Comment: `println(myArray[0])` write something clever

Comment: It outputs 1d arrays just fine when I do it like this, though. Is Processing just not capable of displaying 2d arrays this way?

Comment: In that case, they have provided the output method for the 1-dimensional array, but apparently not for the higher dimensions. Try to loop over the rows and print out every row, if that works that's less code than printing every value :)